# Azure Functions and IP set up

Tags: azure-functions

I have my Azure Function, which has Timer Trigger.
I set up Networking on my IP Address (my current location). I can easily trigger the function with my Visual Studio Code.

Problem is, the function is not running automatic, unless I remove IP Addresses restrictions.

I tried to add inbound IP address of the Function, but this doesn't help.

Any idea what I can try?

Answer (score 0):

1. Created the .NET 6 Azure Function App in the Portal and added the basic HTTP Trigger with Anonymous Authorization Level in it using the Portal.
2. In Networking > Access Restrictions > Allowed all the IP Addresses by specifying the range of `0.0.0.0/0` with the priority 300 and check the Http Trigger and it worked Successfully.
3. Next, I have configured the above Address range to deny and allowed my machine's IP with the priority 200 and refresh the Networking page.

[image]

4. After I refresh the Http trigger Function URL,
   It is working with my IP Address only:

[image]

With the other IP Addresses/Networks, it is restricted to access:

[image]

**Timer Trigger**:

[image]